# Container height listener

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm trying to build a reusable searchBar that can be placed over a listView. Below is a sample of what it looks like

[image]

I've tied the searchBar to the ScrollController and hence can shrink the size of the container using an AnimatedContainer.

The prolem I'm having is that on opening/closing the SearchBar, the child widgets do not gracefully disappear/shrink or reappear. Below is a sample.

[image]

Im trying to do a AnimatedOpacity on them but it looks like I need to tie an AnimationController on the container itself to listen for the height.

I can attach the code, but I'm guessing my question is the approach to take.

- I tried GlobalKey on the container but not every scrollevent is
  caught as I Animate the full stretch of the container when it's
  pulled 50% (to go it a snapping feel).
- I tried SizeChangedLayoutNotifier and am getting the notification, but when I
  tie it to a RenderObject to find the size, I get "Build scheduled
  during frame" error.

Any other ideas ?

Comment: I will suggest Slivers with CustomScroll. 
Otherwise try to go through this:
https://blog.smartnsoft.com/an-automatic-search-bar-in-flutter-flappy-search-bar-a470bc67fa1f

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FPcl1tu0gDs

Comment: My ListView page is based on Slivers. The SearchBar (a resuable Stateful Widget) is inside a SliverToBoxAdapter. The SearchBar is a Container with Row elements.

Comment: I already looked at pub.dev for resuable searchBars like flappy, but none of them have animated look and feel like a Whatsapp searchBar, or default mail app's searchBar in iOS....you pull to snap open and push to snap close

Comment: If you are using Sliver, the use this property: flexibleSpace

in flexible space, you can put your widget. 
I'm also using same in app and works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FPcl1tu0gDs

OR

Here is a little example for your expected result:

```
SliverAppBar(
  expandedHeight: _width / 3.0,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  leading: InkWell(
    onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
    child: Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Container(
          width:  30,
          height: 30,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back,)),
    ),
  ),


  elevation: 0.1,

  title: Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
      left: 16,
    ),
    child: Text(
      "${widget.title}",
      style: TextStyle(
          color: AppTheme.black, fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
    ),
  ),



  floating: true,
  pinned: true,
  snap: false,
  stretch: true,
  centerTitle: false,

// here is custom app searcbar
  flexibleSpace: CustomSearchHeader(
    color: [
      AppTheme.white,
      AppTheme.white,
    ],
    context: context,
    width: _width,
    height: _height,
    onChange: (String value) {
      _jobBloc.add(SearchAddress(listData: _listData, query: value));
    },
  ),
);
```